# How does one determine the rows that have NaN in only some subset of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame with possible NaN values, I'd like to determine which rows have NaN as a value but only for certain columns.

I believe the following should work...

```
my_df.query('colA.isnull() | colZ.isnull() | colN.isnull()')
```

However, I am coming across the following exception

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Now, I've determine that I can pass the param `engine='python'` to get the query to work.  But, I'd like to use the optimized engine `numexpr`.

Is such a query possibly?  Or do I have to iterate over each column I wish to filter on, one at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to build a boolean mask that picks out the row(s) on which any of your conditions is satisfied.

```
# Method 1: build the boolean mask using bitwise operations
 mask = ((df['colA'].isnull()) |
         (df['colZ'].isnull()) | 
         (df['colN'].isnull()))
null_rows = df[mask]

# Method 2: pick desired columns from an element-wise boolean mask of null flags
mask = df.isnull()[['colA', 'colZ', 'colN']].any(axis=1)
null_rows = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the columns and use `df.isna()`.

df (generated using code I copied from somewhere else on SO earlier today, sorry I forget where, but thank you!):

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.763847  1.343149  0.096778       NaN  0.532322
1 -0.364227 -0.560027       NaN       NaN       NaN
2 -0.556234  0.384970  0.476016       NaN -0.385282
3  0.604560 -0.390024 -1.697762  1.207321  0.829520
4       NaN       NaN  0.754011  2.137359 -0.594698
5  0.513925  0.651509 -1.500094       NaN -0.556604
6       NaN       NaN -1.388030       NaN       NaN
7       NaN -0.634743  0.024213 -0.439684  0.765820
8  0.815948  0.545350 -0.823986       NaN  1.655538
9  0.687386  1.477326       NaN  0.207531  0.571499
```

output of `df.isna()`:

```
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False   True  False
1  False  False   True   True   True
2  False  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4   True   True  False  False  False
5  False  False  False   True  False
6   True   True  False   True   True
7   True  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False   True  False
9  False  False   True  False  False
```

Row-wise operations:

```
df.isna().sum(axis=1)
0    1
1    3
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    1
6    4
7    1
8    1
9    1
```

Column-wise:

```
df.isna().sum()
    0    3
    1    2
    2    2
    3    6
    4    2
```

To slice the `df`, use something like `df.loc[:, 0:2].isna()`. You can read up on slicing, `.loc`, and `.iloc` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html